# using python in SQL Server 2017 to call APIs and store data

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've been working on my skill set in Python to call RestAPIs, return/parse the json, and store the results. Ultimately my end goal would be to build programs to bring in our data to our data warehouse.

I've gotten as far as being able to call APIs and store the data into a CSV, and I can open a database connection and run a SQL statement and print the result, but that's my stop gap.

Now that SQL Server 2017 has the capability to run python scripts within SSMS and create stored procedures, I was hoping I could bridge the gap in SQL and call the APIs utilizing Python, return the data, then use SQL to validate and append the data to the right tables.

The only script examples I've seen for Python in SQL Server are for analytics on data already in SQL Server, not on storing data in SQL.

This is what I have so far.

What Python packages do I need, and how would I insert SQL statements/SQL variables into the Python script to use?

```
    --Python Version
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'

import sys
import codecs
import requests
import json

locations = select top(10) locationId from TestDb.locationstable

for j in range(locations):

    url = "http://example.com/api/location/" + locations[j]+ "/users"
    querystring = {"pretty":"1"}
    headers = {"Api-Key": ""}
    r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    d = r.json()
    status = d["status"]
    responseData = d["data"]["Users"]
    print(status)
    print(responseData)
```

The python part works in SQL Server when I take the for loop out and hard code one location into the script, but not sure how to get the locations variable referring to a list of data from the select statement to work within the Python Script.

And then, how would I do something with the returned response data if it returns like this:

```
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
status: 200


STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
[{'id': '123', 'name': 'Sally'}, {'id': '124', 'name': 'Joe'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it really makes sense to execute your SQL statement within a Python script which already resides in your SQL Server instance itself. From my understanding, the benefit of being able to call Python from SQL Server is to be able to access some analytics functions / transformations which wouldn’t be feasible in T-SQL. The logic should be as follow:

1. From T-SQL script call a Python procedure. It can take variables as inputs / arguments if needed and those can come from a previous SQL statement executed directly in your T-SQL environment. In your case it means you can loop over the results of the locations query in T-SQL and call your Python script after for each record of your query.
2. The Python script does it stuff and potentially returns data as output to your SQL script.
3. The SQL script receives the output and continues its job. In your case it could insert the data you fetched from the http request into the table you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/run-python-using-t-sql?view=sql-server-2017

The combination of T-SQL script and Python script seems a bit cumbersome to me. Personally I would suggest to use the Python script for advanced mathematics functions or self contained transformations which you can’t do in SQL. For ETL purpose (Extract Transform and Load), I would suggest you take your Python script outside of SQL server and build yourself a proper Python environment, potentially using Docker. If your script resides outside of SQL Server, there’s  different ways to connect and query your DB. I would suggest you look into Pyodbc.